# How to make HTTP request detecting user clicks out an input

Tags: angular

I having a hard time thinking of how to do this in angular 2. I want make an http request after some few seconds the user clicks out of the input box. The request would be based on the input that the user enters. Any idea on how to do this please? Been thinking hard on this for now. Thanks for your cooperation.

**component**

```
    <div class="form-group" (clickOutside)="makerequest()">
                <input type="email" required>          

  </div>
```

**ts**

```
makerequest(){

 //service here

}
```

Comment: we need code you thought of

Comment: Hi @Beginner, Did you mean by the request take some interval time after to kick the server right.

Comment: yeah exactly. That is after i click outside of the input so the request will be made on the user's input

Comment: @mxr7350. something of this sought :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `(blur)="onBlurMethod()"`
Here's an example :)

Let's say this is your **hey.component.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class HeyService {
  constructor (
    private http: Http
  ) {}

  getUser(arg: string) {
    return this.http.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${arg}`)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

Simple html, **hey.component.html**:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myInput" (blur)="onBlurMethod()">
    <p>{{ profile | json }}</p>
</div>
```

Your component, **hey.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HelloService } from './hey.component.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './hey.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hey.component.css']
})
export class HeyComponent {
  myInput: string;
  profile = {};

  constructor(private heyService: HeyService) {
  }

  onBlurMethod() {
    this.loadUser(this.myInput);
  }

  loadUser(arg: string) {
    this.userService.getUser(this.myInput).subscribe(data => this.profile = data);
  }
}
```

*Reminder to add the service to the providers in the app module if you are using a separate service.*

In your specific example, the **Html** will look like this:

```
<div class="form-group" (blur)="makeRequest()">
  <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="email" required>
</div>
```

and the **ts**:

```
email: string;

...

makeRequest(){
  this.yourService.yourMethod(this.email);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a function for outside of click in the input fields. This function inside write the following http request in angular 2 will be working. You will try it.

```
let myRequest = this.http.get(...);
let pollingSubscription = myRequest.expand(() => Observable.timer(5000).flatMap(() => myRequest));
.subscribe();
```